# How to configure multi-threading in TestNG having @DataProvider, @Factory and one @Test method

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor, testng, dataprovider

I want to have multi-threading in my class, i.e., my `@Test` method should run in parallel.

The test class has one `@Test` annotated method, one `@DataProvider` and one `@Factory` method which is a constructor of my test-class.

I have also overridden `getTestName(ITest class)` method. My test-data has 28 scenarios.

**EDIT**

```
@Listeners com.loyalty.HTMLReporter.class
public class TestClass implemented ITest {

@DataProvider 
public static Object[][] dp () {
//I read test data from a file. The test-data could vary from 2 to 1000         
//scenarios.
Object tests [][] = new Object [testcaseIdMap.keyset().toArray().length][];

    for (Object ket : testcaseIdMap.keySet().toArray()){
        tests[i] = new Object[1];
        tests[i][0] = key.toString();
        i++;
    }
return tests 
}

@Factory (dataProvider = "dp")
public TestClass (String testcaseId) {
this.testcaseId = testcaseId;
}

@Test
public void TC () {
//some code
}

@Override
public String getTestName () {
return testcaseId;
}

@BeforeSuite
public void createDBConnection () {
// some code
}

@AfterSuite
public void failedTestCases () {
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your test methods parallel, create a test suite xml file like below

```
<suite name="Your suite name" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" >
    <test name="Your test name">
        <classes>
            <class name="packagename.classname" />
        </classes>
     </test>
</suite>
```

Set number of threads as per your need.

If you want to run your dataprovider parallel, then add parallel=true in the dataprovider annotation.

```
@DataProvider(name = "dataprovidername",parallel=true)
```

Comment: I have one @Test method in the test class, so this will not be suitable for me. I want to run this single Test method parallelly with data-coming from DataProvider

Comment: I have added my code. Can you tell me where do i add number of threads? Since test-data is variable, how will i decide the value for invocation-counts?
Also can you tell what is difference in making DataProvider as paralle and in marking parallel in suite tag?

Comment: I now want to add two Test cases. First Test case will run in parallel with values provided from DataProvider. After that I want to run second test case without any DataProvider and multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html and read:
**5.6.2 - Parameters with DataProviders**
Also under:
**5.10 - Parallelism and time-outs**
You will find informations how to create your test_suite.xml to run test parallelly

Comment: My problem is something else.
1 Test method in the test-class which also has DataProvider and Factory method. I want this single Test method to run parallely